# Fillable PDF form that requires multiple calculations

Tags: javascript

The list below is what I'm trying to get to work.  So, lets say I enter whole numbers in each group giving me a total at the end, then the total on top auto populates with those totals.  Then the percentages at the bottom also auto populates based on the formula added (Men, Woman, Gender for African divide by Total on top).  I keep getting error messages because I think it's to many for the calculation fields.

```
Total: __________     Total Men________  Woman________

         African   Hisp   Asian.  Italian  White   Unknown   TOTAL

MEN     ______   ______  _____    ____     ______  ______     ______

WOMEN  _______  ______   _____    ____    ______   ______     ______

UNKNOWN

GENDER  ______  _____   _____    _____    _____    ______     ______
```

Approximate ethnic and racial breakdown of the applicant pool:

```
African   Hisp   Asian  Amer. Ind  Italian White   Unknown        TOTAL

_____%  _____%   ____%  _____%     _________%      _______%   ________%
```

Comment: More specifics? Is this PDF? JavaScript? Both? Share any problem code and error messages.

Comment: I guess I should state that I do not know Java.  I sued the simple instructions in the field.  Is there a way of attaching the file here?

Comment: @Rosa FYI, Java != JavaScript. They are two completely different languages.

Comment: See! Didn't even know that!  Sorry!

Comment: Please someone help me!  Maybe I can send form via email?